# Ant read files in a directory and regex

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to read the names of a set of files in a directory and apply regex to those names and obtain a list with comma seperated values. The names of the files are in the format of build_level1_D1.properties, build_level1.D2.properties, build_level2.D1.properties etc...
I need to read all the file names and apply regex and parse the names to get level1_D1, level1_D2, level2_D1 etc.. I need it in the format of  property name="build.levels" value="level1_D1,level1_D2,level2_D1"    This is what i tried. Need some pointers and help.

```
    <target name="build-levels-all">
            <for param="program">
                <path><fileset dir="${root.build.path}/build" includes="*"/>
                </path>
                 <sequential>
                    <propertyregex override="yes" property="file" input="@{program}" regexp="build\_([^\.]*)" select="\1" />
                    <echo>${file}</echo>
                 </sequential> 
            </for>
            <echo>${program}</echo>
<-- This prints the files regexed Level1_D1, level2_D2 etc....But i need to capture it in the format of <property name="build.levels" value="level1_D1,level1_D2,level2_D1" /> -->
            </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an embedded scripting language, like [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task), to do this kind of complex logic.

```
   <target name="process-files">
      <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

      <groovy>
         def list = []

         new File('build').eachFile() {
            def matcher = it.name =~ /(build_level\d_D\d).properties/
            list.add matcher[0][1]
         }

         properties."build.levels" = list.join(",")
      </groovy>
   </target>

   <target name="doSomething" depends="process-files">
      <echo>${build.levels}</echo>
   </target>
```

Just like ant-contrib, groovy needs an additional jar. I normally include a "bootstrap" target to install this:

```
   <target name="bootstrap">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.6/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar"/>
   </target>
```